# Multithreading on UNIX with OpenGl

Tags: multithreading, unix, opengl

I want to load assets for my OpenGL application in a separate thread so that I can create a loading screen, but when I try to call an OpenGL function in another thread, the application crashes, and I need them to load textures. Is there anyway I can use multithreading and OpenGL? Or am I going to say, load an asset every frame, and make the screen kinda choppy and bad looking? I've seen that you can accomplish this on Windows, but I want this to run on Unix (specifically MacOSX) much more than windows.

Answer (score 4):

Messing with a single OpenGL context in different threads is usually bound to result in trouble. What you can do though is make use of a [Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) for the texture update, map this in the main (OpenGL) thread, pass the mapped pointer to the loading thread to be filled with file contents, and unmap the PBO followed by a `glTexImage2D` (using the PBO, of course) in the main thread once the loading thread has finished. By using two different PBOs, one that is currently filled by the loading thread and one that is currently copied into a texture by the main thread and some proper synchronization, you can get the file loading and texture update to work concurrently (look at the linked tutorial for some, yet single-threaded, examples).

Comment: So I do have to run them in the same thread, but this would be faster?